# Seeing the moon or its light for Kiddush Levanah

Tags: halacha, kiddush-levanah

When you say Kiddush Levanah, how much of the moon do you have to see? Is seeing its light ok?

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=633&st=&pgnum=49 argues you don't have to see any of it at all, even if it's completely overcast.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Enough moonlight that, assuming no other lighting, a person can benefit from it ( he can do things that he wouldn't be able to do without the moon).   Mishna Berura 426:3

Comment: Just the light you do not have to see the Moon?

Comment: Sorry, I thought the question was about seeing a fuzzy moon.  Whether the light is the ikar or the moon itself ("Haroeh levana b'chidusho") is a machlokes acharonim.  The main machlokes plays itself out regarding a blind person.  The biur halacha says it's better to be yotze off someone else.  Regarding your specific case, is it possible to have benefit from the light without seeing the moon?  (Seeing the moon means seeing the light reflected from the surface.)

Comment: sure through the clouds

Comment: Although I can't say for sure, I suspect that if the cloud is so thick that you cannot see light reflected off the moon itself, you may not have beneficial light.  Otherwise, why argue about a Sumah, argue about everyone on a cloudy night.